# how do i get a jest/enzyme test to pass this require statement containing a path and a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I'm trying to test a react module that contains the code `` <img alt='avatar' src={require(`../../assets/${avatar}`)} /> `` which concats a path and a prop containing a file name received from the redux store. It renders fine but the test throws the error *"Cannot find module '../../assets/' from 'UserProfile.js'"* which sounds like it thinks the path is a module. The full code is as follows:

The module

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const UserProfile = ({name='', avatar=''}) => {

    return (
        <section className='bg-bright padding-m'>
            <img alt='avatar' src={require(`../../assets/${avatar}`)} />
            {name}
        </section>
    )

}

UserProfile.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    avatar: PropTypes.string
}

export default UserProfile
```

The test

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import UserProfile from '../../../src/components/ui/UserProfile'

describe('<UserProfile /> component', () => {
    it('renders enclosing html tag', () => 
        expect(
            shallow(<UserProfile />)
                .find('section')
                .length
            ).toBe(1)
        )
})
```

The redux store data it's using looks something like

```
{
    "name": "a name",
    "avatar": "name.jpg"
  }
```

The error

```
● <UserProfile /> component › renders enclosing html tag

    Cannot find module '../../assets/' from 'UserProfile.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
      at Object.UserProfile [as type] (src/components/ui/UserProfile.js:8:72)
      at ReactShallowRenderer.render (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer-shallow.development.js:104:34)
      at node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:289:35
      at withSetStateAllowed (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/build/Utils.js:93:16)
```

The line in question renders as

```
<img alt="avatar" src="/static/media/admin.34e378b0.jpg">
```

If anyone has any insights it'd be appreciated. If the insights involve a better way to return the image path that would be fine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to pass some props when shallow rendering your component:

```
describe('<UserProfile /> component', () => {
    it('renders enclosing html tag', () => 
        expect(
            shallow(<UserProfile name="fakeName" avatar="fakeAvatar" />)
                .find('section')
                .length
        ).toBe(1);
    );
});
```

Then after that enzyme will look for a module at the path `../../assets/${avatar}` so in the case of the test above: `../../assets/fakeAvatar`

There is obviously nothing at that path so you need to mock it:

```
jest.mock('../../assets/fakeAvatar', () => 'fake/image/url.png');
```

So your full test would be

```
describe('<UserProfile /> component', () => {
    it('renders enclosing html tag', () => 
        jest.mock('../../assets/fakeAvatar', () => 'fake/image/url.png');
        expect(
            shallow(<UserProfile name="fakeName" avatar="fakeAvatar" />)
                .find('section')
                .length
        ).toBe(1);
    );
});
```

Comment: I played around with this for a bit, the original error was: Cannot find module '../../assets/' from 'UserProfile.js' — 

The error from your solution was:  Cannot find module '../../assets/fakeAvatar' from 'UserProfile.js' — 

Since it was looking for a '../../assets/' not '../../assets/fakeAvatar' module i changed it to that in the mock and got: '../../assets/fakeAvatar' from 'UserProfile.js' — 

Then I decided to move the mock outside the it function and got: Cannot find module '../../assets/' from 'UserProfileNew.test.js' —  

I dunno