# how to specify an image path when the file name is in the redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I have a react/redux app built on create-react-app (so no webpack, sigh, i cld eject i guess wldnt be a big deal) with image file names in the redux store. In order to render the images I have to provide a path to them. This bit of code is the only thing that's worked so far `` <img src={require(`../../assets/${avatar}`)} /> `` but it seems hacky to put a require statement in the render function. Also I can't figure out how to test it ([how do i get a jest/enzyme test to pass this require statement containing a path and a prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584435/how-do-i-get-a-jest-enzyme-test-to-pass-this-require-statement-containing-a-path/47585346#47585346)). My app currently has no routing but I will eventually add some so if I could use react-router to solve this problem then I will. The relevant code looks like:

The module

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const UserProfile = ({name='', avatar=''}) => {

    return (
        <section className='bg-bright padding-m'>
            <img alt='avatar' src={require(`../../assets/${avatar}`)} />
            {name}
        </section>
    )

}

UserProfile.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    avatar: PropTypes.string
}

export default UserProfile
```

The redux store data it's using looks something like

```
{
    "name": "a name",
    "avatar": "name.jpg"
  }
```

The line in question renders as

```
<img alt="avatar" src="/static/media/admin.34e378b0.jpg">
```

Thx!

Comment: Whats the problem here ?

Comment: My current solution seems hackish, I feel like there must be a sounder way, as evidenced by tests considering that require statement to be a module, also I can't figure out how to get the test to pass.

Answer (score 0):

> seems hacky to put a require statement in the render function

Of course, provided code works properly only because appropriate `webpack` plugin is enabled, and loader like `image-loader` is provided.
When some relative path is provided, `webpack` performs including all root directory in target dist build, and then in runtime performs variable reading and fetching resource from dist build https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-context
If you want, just reconfigure `webpack-config` in part of media resolver: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L157